# How to replace in values in spark dataframes after recalculations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a schema in spark as

```
root
|-- atom: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
| -- titlename: string (nullable = true)
```

I have extracted the `utcacquisitiontime` and `datatimezone` as below from above schema

```
val result=q.selectExpr("explode(dailydata) as r").select("r.utcacquisitiontime","r.datatimezone")

+--------------------+------------+
|  utcacquisitiontime|datatimezone|
+--------------------+------------+
|2017-03-27T22:00:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T22:15:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T22:30:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T22:45:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T23:00:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T23:15:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T23:30:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-27T23:45:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T00:00:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T00:15:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T00:30:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T00:45:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T01:00:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T01:15:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T01:30:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T01:45:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T02:00:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T02:15:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T02:30:00Z|      +02:00|
|2017-03-28T02:45:00Z|      +02:00|
+--------------------+------------+
```

I need to calculate `localtime` using these two columns and replace them by the `localtime` after calculations. How shall I calculate `localtime` and replace the same?

Comment: you can use `withColumn` method on dataframe and use [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on udf function in spark (User Defined Function). Also in the org.apache.sql.functions._ there are plenty of already predefined function that might help you. But here is how you can make this work

```
+-------------------+------------+
| utcacquisitiontime|datatimezone|
+-------------------+------------+
|2017-03-27T22:00:00|      +02:00|
+-------------------+------------+
```

Note that I have removed the unnecessary "Z" from time column.
Using JodaTime dependency define a udf function like this:

```
val toTimestamp = udf((time:String, zone:String) => {
      val timezone = DateTimeZone.forID(zone)
     val df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
     new java.sql.Timestamp(df.withZone(timezone).parseDateTime(time).getMillis)
     })
```

Apply it on a column with `withColumn`

```
df.withColumn("timestamp", toTimestamp(col("utcacquisitiontime"), col("datatimezone"))
```

Show the results (note that in the schema the column timestamp is of type Timestamp so you can do date operation on it)

```
+-------------------+------------+--------------------+
| utcacquisitiontime|datatimezone|           timestamp|
+-------------------+------------+--------------------+
|2017-03-27T22:00:00|      +02:00|2017-01-27 22:00:...|
+-------------------+------------+--------------------+

root
 |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks!! it helped!

Comment: How do I append only `timestamp` to root? If you could help, that would really be appreciated.

Comment: df.drop("utcacquisitiontime").drop("datatimezone"). Please also up vote if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Joda Time](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/) API to convert time in your df column to the localtime by doing something like,

```
def convertToLocal(str:String):String = new DateTime(str).toLocalDateTime().toString
```

next you import sql implicits by,

```
import ss.implicits._
```

where ss is the instance of your `SparkSession`. To convert each element of utcacquisitiontime column to localDateTime, do something like this,

```
val df=result map(r=>(convertToLocal(r.getString(0)),r.getString(1)))

df show
```

Let me know if this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Could you pease help me how do I append this new df to the original json schema that I have as above such that `utcacquisitiontime` | `datatimezone` are replaced by new `localtimestamp` calculated?