# Always get "1970" when extracting a year from timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a timestamp like "1461819600". The I execute this code in a distributed environment as `val campaign_startdate_year: String = Utils.getYear(campaign_startdate_timestamp).toString`

The problem is that I always get the same year `1970`. Which might be the reason of it?

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

def getYear(timestamp: Any): Int = {
    var dt = 2017
    if (!timestamp.toString.isEmpty)
    {
      dt = new DateTime(timestamp.toString.toLong).getYear // toLong should be multiplied by 1000 to get millisecond value
    }
    dt
  }
```

The same issue occurs when I want to get a day of a month. I get `17` instead of `28`.

```
  def getDay(timestamp: Any): Int = {
    var dt = 1
    if (!timestamp.toString.isEmpty)
    {
      dt = new DateTime(timestamp.toString.toLong).getDayOfYear
    }
    dt
  }
```

Comment: `1970` is the yrear of the timestamp `0`. Are you sure that your `toLong` conversion does not return a `0` value ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: Why does it return `0` if a string is not empty? If it would be empty, then I would get `2017` because of `if (!timestamp.toString.isEmpty)`.

Comment: The `string` may be a `string` like `abc`. The `type` of `timestamp` is `Any` so it could be anything other than a number so a `toLong` may fails by returning a `0` value.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: I am pretty sure that these are numbers. But the issue might be related to a distributed environment...

Comment: I do not think that it's related to distributed environment, just to example it *new DateTime("123".toString.toLong).getYear* it will give you 1970. So if timestamp it's not a really timestamp but a dummy number you getYear it will give you 1970

Comment: @dumitru: Ok, thanks. I will revise it.

Comment: @dumitru Is there any other function to get year, month, day of month?

Comment: `new java.util.Date(1461819600L)` returns `Sat Jan 17 16:03:39 CST 1970`. Multiply 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp you have is a number of **seconds** since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Java (and Scala) usually use timestamps that are a number of **milliseconds** since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

In other words, you need to multiply the number with 1000.

Comment: I would use java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMllis(s) instead of just multiplying by a 'magic number'

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp that you have seems to be in *seconds* since the epoch (i.e. a Unix timestamp). Java time utilities expect the timestamp to be in *milliseconds*.

Just multiply that value by `1000` and you should get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on either on spark sql function which have some [date utilities](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) (get year/month/day, add day/month) or you can use JodaTime library to have more control over Date and DateTime, like in my answer here: [How to replace in values in spark dataframes after recalculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325440/how-to-replace-in-values-in-spark-dataframes-after-recalculations/45328560?noredirect=1#comment77628652_45328560)

Comment: Also, `java.time.{Instance,LocalDateTime,LocalDate}`